# Calculate Bitmap size from decoded bounds

Tags: android, bitmap

Is it possible to extimate a Bitmap's size in memory before actually decoding it? I was running into OutOfMemoryErrors and wouldn't want to try an allocation if there's not enough heap space left. If I set BitmapFactory.Options.justDecodeBounts to true I will get the width and height of the resulting Bitmap:

```
// Decode image size
BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, o);
Log.d(getClass().getName(),"Input image size: "+o.outWidth+"x"+o.outHeight);
```

Is there an easy way to get to the Bitmap's size without having to calculate it from the dimensions?

I was going to work around the issue by multiplying width*height*4 for ARGB_8888 to get the byte count of the resulting image. This is fairly precise but the resulting Bitmap's byte count is a bit higher than that. How would I go about and take this overhead of the Bitmap Object into account?  I am not planning to re-use the bitmap so this should hopefully work with KitKat's getAllocationByteCount().

Comment: `width * height * 4`, if using **ARBG_8888** (4 bytes describing each pixel's Alpha, Red, Green and Blue components). So, 1280*720 = 3686400 bytes = about 3.686 MB

Comment: That's what I am doing now but there is still an overhead of a few bytes that I would like to calculate precisely instead of guessing. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not `guessing`. It's called **math**.

Comment: I realised that there is indeed no overhead. The image was decoded using inSampleSize > 1 (not shown in code sample) so I divided o.outWidth and o.outHeight by inSampleSize to calculate the resulting size. This obviously isn't accurate if width or height are odd integers.